# How to install Shopify App with no auth scopes?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api-node

My Shopify App only requires the store information in order to perform all of its functions. Is there a way to allow the app to install without setting any specific auth scopes? I'm running into errors when leaving the env value null.

By default the CLI uses the following `SCOPES=write_products,write_customers,write_draft_orders`. I don't need access to any of these.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if this works but try this out:

1.) Navigate to your index.js file.

2.) Search for Shopify.Context.initialize({

3.) Replace

```
SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
```

with

```
SCOPES: [],
```

This should be all. I hope I could help you with my answer.

Reference:

[Shopify API Access Scopes](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/access-scopes)

Comment: It doesn't seem like that's going to work. Running into ```ShopifyError: Cannot initialize Shopify API Library. Missing values for: SCOPES``` in the terminal when running ```shopify app serve```.

Comment: Did you replace the SCOPES value with [] ?

Comment: I think you have to remove the entirely Shopify.Context.initialize({ because this command initializes that you can make authenticated API Calls. Just delete the Shopify.Context.initialize({ and you should be done here.

Comment: Let me now if it worked. Best regards TheDeveloperFrontend

Comment: I cannot remove that code since I need it for API calls.